# What is the expected error code returned if the IoTHub device is disabled while still connected?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I would like to know what is the expected error code returned if the IoTHub device is disabled while still connected in the IoTHub.
I tested it with the scenario below:

**Scenario A:**

1. Device is connected to iothub.
2. Disable the device in azure iot explorer.
3. Device was disconnected.

**Actual result:** Error code received was **IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_NO_NETWORK**

I expect that the error code should be **IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_DEVICE_DISABLED**

**Scenario B:**

1. Disable the device first in iothub.
2. Device will attempt the connection.
   **Actual result:** error code received was **IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_DEVICE_DISABLED**

Scenario B is expected. How about scenario A?

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: That's a good question. 
IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_DEVICE_DISABLED ->Device could not be authenticated because it is disabled by the user on the Azure IoT Hub (see field State in Device Explorer)
IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_NO_NETWORK -> If retry policy is disabled, these error reasons might be provided to indicate there is a network connection issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems related to the limited error reporting in MQTT 3.1.1. The server will drop the connection when the device is disabled in IoTHub, it has no implicit mechanism to tell the client why it was disconnected.  The client experiences network issue which then gets surfaced.

In the second case once the TCP connection is initiated the server expects CONNECT frame but as the device is disabled the server returns 0x03 which is translated as disabled. The possible errors are again limited as you can see in the specs. http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html section 3.2.2.3

Comment: Thank you for sharing the related specs. I will check it.As of now, I am waiting for a response from microsoft team in https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/2300.

Comment: Microsoft Azure team answered the question same as your answer. They DISCONNECT packet does not have any field to specify the reason. They also said that it will be supported maybe in MQTTv5.